# Not Able to do API Calls in ReactNative App

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I am building a ReactNative based App by learning from Internet.

I am now just trying to do simple API Call inside the app.

The same API is working in other projects, but for me its not.

I am not able to figure it out whether Its ReactNative Issue or API Issue. As per me it can not be API Issue.

My App has --

```
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
"react-native": "0.44.0",
```

I am running app via `react-native run-ios` command.

Based on my searching of the issue, I have already tried these things - but still not success.

1. Adding All `AppTransportSecurity` things inside `info.plist`.
2. Deleting and installing again all Node Modules.
3. Tried by running the same on Android, still same.

My Code for API Call -

```
fetch(api.login(this.state.email,this.state.password), {
                method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        'Accept': 'application/json',
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        //'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        'email': this.state.email,
                        'password': this.state.password
                    })
                })
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((responseData) => {

                    if(responseData.status===200){

                        if(Platform.OS==="ios"){
                            Alert.alert( 'Success',"", { cancelable: false });
                        }else{
                            ToastAndroid.show('Success', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                        }

                        //storageHelper.saveUser(responseData.data.user_id.toString());
                        //this.fetchUserProfile();
                    }else{
                        if(Platform.OS==="ios"){
                            Alert.alert( 'Please try again',"", { cancelable: false });
                        }else{
                            ToastAndroid.show('Please try again', ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .catch(e => {

                    if(Platform.OS==="ios"){
                        Alert.alert('error','Login fail'+JSON.stringify(e), { cancelable: false });
                    }else{
                        ToastAndroid.show('Error : Login fail'+JSON.stringify(e), ToastAndroid.SHORT);
                    }
                })
                .done();
```

And I am getting this error from `catch` condition -

```
Login fail{"line":15259, "column":29,"sourceURL":"http://localhost:8081/index.ios.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false"}
```

I am stuck on the Issue, Need a solution.

Thanks,

Comment: There's an error in your code. Thats your react-native bundle crashing. Whats api.login fonction ?

Comment: `static login(email,password){
        return Constants.BASE_URL+"/api/users/login?email"+email+"&password="+password;
    }` --- this function just gives the URL for API. @WilomGfx

Comment: where does this fetch reside in ? maybe your `this.state` is undefined. Have you tried debugging ? or manual console.log debugging ?

Comment: @WilomGfx : The api url is perfect also params are perfect including headers. I have checked out these. Still I have no idea what missing. It always going into `catch` condition.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  This is infuriating. Absolutely no info in the error and also already bypassed iOS https security with plist key.